# FPDF switch or if statement in cell

Tags: php, fpdf

i am trying to beautify output of join two strings in a cell.

i am using the following line so far.

```
Code:
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],5,$row['month_01_A'] . ' - ' .  $row['month_01_B'],0,0,'R');
Output:
129 - 10
50 - 120
231 - 5
```

I would like to have an alignment in `-` and have the desire output:

```
129 -  10
 50 - 120
231 -   5
```

I was think to use `if` or `switch` and count length of `$row['month_01_A']` and `$row['month_01_B']` and output the desire spacing in `-`.

Tried the following code(fixing the second part) but didn't work:

```
$t=strlen($row['month_01_B']);
switch ($t) {
  case "1":
    $mmm=$row['month_01_A'] . '-  ' .$row['month_01_B']; 
  case "2":
    $mmm=$row['month_01_A'] . '- ' .$row['month_01_B']; 
  case "3":
    $mmm=$row['month_01_A'] . '-' .$row['month_01_B'];
  default:
    $mmm="000";
}
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],5,$mmm,0,0,'R');
```

I am getting this output always:

```
000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it and i have two solutions.
One is with working code above.

```
$t=strlen($row['month_01_B']);
switch ($t) {
  case "1":
    $mmm=$row['month_01_A'] . '-  ' .$row['month_01_B']; 
    break;
  case "2":
    $mmm=$row['month_01_A'] . '- ' .$row['month_01_B'];
    break;
  case "3":
    $mmm=$row['month_01_A'] . '-' .$row['month_01_B'];
    break;
  default:
    $mmm="000";
}
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],5,$mmm,0,0,'R');
```

Second is to split my cell into 3. The first cell for value A, the second for my symbol and last one for my second value B.